# REST не возвращает страницу

Tags: java, html, rest, controller

Метод REST.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create_HTML_Page_with_new_coordinates/{x}/{y}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> getLinktoHTMLPageFromJBossTempDirectory(@PathVariable("x") int x, @PathVariable("y") int y) {
        String link;
        ResponsePageHtml responsePageHtml = new ResponsePageHtml(x, y);
        responsePageHtml.writeHTMLtoTempJBOSS();
        link = responsePageHtml.getFullFilePATH();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(link, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

тут суть такая. у меня есть класс ResponsePageHtml который создает страницу html которая содержит небольшой яндекс апи по отображению карты по переданным координатам.

я создаю страницу, она записывается в директорию bin Jboss и потом я возвращаю ссылку на нее.

Но после выполнения метода вместо того чтобы отобразилась страница отображается такая надпись.

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

страница html создается и при открытии нормально отображает карту.

Comment: а Вы не пробовали debug-ом прогнать?? И перепроверьте правильно ли у вас создаётся страница

Comment: да конечно я дебажил. страница создается верно. в браузере потом открывается норм без ошибок.

Comment: я может не правильно Вас понимаю, но вы писали, что у вас после выполнения метода отображается надпись "This page contains the following errors: ...", а сейчас вы пишите, что всё норм. Объясните, пожалуйста, конкретнее, что и в каком порядке вы делаете

Comment: в дебаге проходит по всем строкам метода ResponseEntity<String> getLinktoHTMLPageFromJBossTempDirectory(@PathVariable("x") int x, @PathVariable("y") int y) {
        String link;
        ResponsePageHtml responsePageHtml = new ResponsePageHtml(x, y);
        responsePageHtml.writeHTMLtoTempJBOSS();
        link = responsePageHtml.getFullFilePATH();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(link, HttpStatus.OK);
    }  все ок. создается новый файл в директории bin. file.html я хочу чтобы он открылся но вместо этого появляется надпись как выше

Comment: а какая ссылка до файла у Вас в дебаге??

Comment: ссылка до директории где лежит файл C:\\....\\dir\\

Comment: Как я понимаю у вас программы пытается вывести html-файл, и берёт она его по полному пути (С:\\...) Но Ваш сервер не знает такого пути. Он воспринимает только то, что лежит в его ресурсах. Как мне кажется, Вам нужно, чтобы файл оказывался в папке webapp/ваш_файл.html и для открытия его необходимо сделать на него response.redirect("ваш_фай.html")

Comment: очень годная идея, спасибо!))